# Are two independent events still independent if taking the contradiction of one?

Tags: probability, probability-theory, statistics, discrete-mathematics, independence

Let's say we have independent events E1 and E2. Does this also mean that !E1 and E2 are independent? And if not can someone give me an example where !E1 and E2 are dependent?

Comment: What does it mean for $E_2$ and $E_1^c$ to be independent?  Is the condition true?

Comment: It just means that your basic independence conditions are satisfied e.g. ```P(E1|E2) = P(E1), P(E2|E1) = P(E2), P(E1 ∩ E2) = P(E1)*P(E2)```

Comment: The last one is the one you need.  Can you determine if $\Pr(E_1\cap E_2^c)=\Pr(E_1)\cdot\Pr(E_2^c)$?  By the way, your posts will ook better, be easier to read, and get better response if you format them with [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference)

Answer (score 0):

Let $\Pr(E_1)=p_1$ and $\Pr(E_2)=p_2$.  We are given that $E_1$ and $E_2$ are independent, that is $$\Pr(E_1\cap E_2)=p_1p_2$$
Since $$E_1=(E_1\cap E_2)\cup(E_1\cap E_2^c)$$ and the two sets on the right are disjoint, we have
$$\begin{align}
\Pr(E_1)&=\Pr(E_1\cap E_2)+\Pr(E_1\cap  E_2^c)\\
p_1&=p_1p_2+\Pr(E_1\cap E_2^c)\\
p_1(1-p_2)&=\Pr(E_1\cap E_2^c)\\
\Pr(E_1)\Pr(E_2^c)&=\Pr(E_1\cap E_2^c)
\end{align}$$
and we see that $E_1$ and $E_2^c$ are independent.